# Guile syntax-rules matching confusion on elipsis and improper list in the GNU manual

Tags: scheme, guile

I'm having difficulty following along with some of the GNU guile manual's documentation on macros (https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/guile.pdf) :

In section 6.10.2.1 (pg 259 on Patterns), there's a section talking about how improper lists are matched like the elipsis keyword:

```
(define-syntax let1
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ (var val) . exps)
     (let ((var val)) . exps))))
```

Then saying how this is non-desirable because non-list `exps` like in `(let (foo 'bar) . baz))` will be matched. However, I can't get that expression to expand. The following expressions do expand, though:

- `(let1 (foo 'bar) . (baz))` → `(let (foo 'bar) baz)`
- `(let1 (foo 'bar) baz)` → `(let (foo 'bar) baz)`

Similarly in the following discussion on the improvement:

```
(define-syntax let1
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ (var val) exp ...)
     (let ((var val)) exp ...))))
```

It states that `(let1 (foo 'bar))` will be matched, which I once again can't get to match. I can get this to, though:

- `(let1 (foo 'bar) baz)` → `(let (foo 'bar) baz)`

Before bashing my head against the wall any further, it would be great if someone can clarify how the improper and elipsis pattern matching worked (and whether there's a typo in the documentation, or something wrong with my Guile installation/macro expansion methodology?). I'm using Guile 2.0.9 (docs are on 2.0.11 but wouldn't have thought this would matter so much), and I'm using [Geiser](http://www.nongnu.org/geiser/geiser_5.html#Cheat-sheet), as well as [this guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/docs/master/guile.html/Macro-Expansion.html) for macro expansion (no difference in result):

```
ice-9/psyntax.scm:1101:54: In procedure expand-top-sequence:
ice-9/psyntax.scm:1101:54: Syntax error:
unknown location: let: bad let in form (let ((foo (quote bar))))

In ice-9/psyntax.scm:
1101:54  0 (expand-top-sequence ((let2 (foo (quote bar)))) () ((top)) ...)
```

Thanks! Also, if anyone can recommend any other good, less terse resources on Scheme (preferentially in Guile) macros that would be great as well!

Comment: Try this for size: http://hipster.home.xs4all.nl/lib/scheme/gauche/define-syntax-primer.txt

Comment: A good reference is the redoubtable Mr Dybvig's book: http://www.scheme.com/tspl3/ Not specifically for Guile. As far as I know there are no textbooks on Guile.